# What do you set root :to in api-only rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Very basic question that I've having difficulty getting an answer for: I have a rails application that I am only using as an api server. My entire front-end is handled by an EmberJS app. I've noticed a particular pattern in my logs:

`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):`

What do I set the root url to so that I stop getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid the error, and have nothing at the root you could make this the root route

```
root to: proc { [200, {}, ['']] }
```

Which will just return an empty string and status 200.

It may be better to return 404 however, considering there isn't a resource available at the root.